# not able to send mail to group in python gae

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine

I want to send mail to the group. But Mail API is not sending to group id.

Here is my code

```
from google.appengine.api import mail
import traceback
class Mail:    
    # mail with html content    
    def send(self,emailFrom,emailTo,emailSubject,emailBody,emailHtml):
        try:
            logging.info("Mail From : " + emailFrom)
            message = mail.EmailMessage(sender=emailFrom,
                            subject=emailSubject)
            message.to = emailTo

            message.body = emailBody
            message.html = emailHtml
            result = message.send()
            logging.info("Mail Sent. To : " + emailTo + ' Subject : '+emailSubject)
            return "EmailSent"
        except Exception, err:
            logging.info("Unable to send email to " + emailTo + " : " + traceback.format_exc())
            return "ErrorInSendingEmail"
```

this is not showing any error on developer console logging.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to send mails to individual ids? If yes and if the group is a internal group, which is exclusive to your organisation,you might want to check the google group settings and see if it has permissions to accept mails from external mail ids(mail ids which do not end with @yourorg.com)

Comment: Yes. I am able to send mail to individual ids.

Comment: Is the group internal group? Then please check the setting i mentioned

Comment: I can send the mail abc@myorg.com,abc1@myorg.com,abc2@myorg.com individually. There is a group id group@myorg.com contains above email ids. I think there should be no problem then? and which setting ?

Comment: Is your script mailing with sender-id, something@myorg.com , if not you need to change either the sender-id so that it is something@myorg.com or make your google group public, so that anyone with a ID which doesn't end with @myorg.com can send mails to your group.
You can check this link on how to make your group public.
https://support.google.com/a/answer/170452

Comment: I have exactly the same issue